# How does github pages serve files?

Tags: html, web, server, hosting

My understanding on how Web hosting works is that you require some sort of technology to serve content, even if it's just an HTML file. I thought that simply putting an html file on a server running nothing at all (no Apache, etc), and going to {server_ip}/path/to/.html will not serve it over http.

So I've Googled and to no avail, I cannot find out what technology github pages is using to serve static pages

Answer (score 1):

A server by definition is a program, not a computer. You put an HTML file on a computer, not a server.

Github use pretty sophisticated technology, not a single server. You can read about that [here](https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast).